# Change value of textBox from different class?

Tags: .net, oop, class, c++-cli

If I have a C++/CLI form with `textbox1` and a class called `Dummy` in another header file, what can I do if I want to change "directly" the value of `textbox1.Text` by a function exists in Dummy class?

Comment: You mean `myForm->textbox1->Text = whatever;`?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, but I already included Dummy.h in myForm.h.. but I can't include myForm.h in Dummy.h!

Comment: Put this line in `Dummy.cpp`, which includes both `Dummy.h` and `myform.h`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thanks it works. How can accept you answer?

Comment: I have to write it like an answer first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ does single-pass compilation.  That means you can't use something until the compiler has already seen it.

When you have two classes using each other mutually, that can be tricky.  Luckily C++ also allows forward declaration, which tells the compiler "Here is the signature for a class or function I'm going to provide you with later".

In general, provide the compiler with the following, in this order:

- forward declaration of classes

  ```
  ref class Dummy;
  ref class MyForm;
  ```
- class definitions

  ```
  ref class Dummy { ... };
  ref class MyForm { ... };
  ```
- class member function definitions

  ```
  void Dummy::DoIt()
  {
      myForm->textBox1->Text = whatever;
  }
  ```

Often, the only thing needed is to put function definitions in a .cpp file, and make sure that .cpp file `#include`s the header file for every class.  For your problem, that'd mean you should put this line in `Dummy.cpp`, which includes both `Dummy.h` and `myform.h`.

Answer (score 0):

How about pass the variable as TextBox Object to the dummy class then,
Dummy makes changes and return a TextBox Object

```
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox ChangeText(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox MyTextBox)
{
    MyTextBox.Text = "HELLO";
    return MyTextBox;
}
```

this is a method in a class from C# maybe you can use the same logic.